# How to apply rate limiting for Meteor Subscriptions?

Tags: meteor, ddp

Although it seems very easy to implement, `DDP Rate Limiting` for `Meteor Subscriptions` seems to be not working.
I have the following code snippet in "/imports/api/server" folder.

```
Meteor.publish('todos.public', function todosPublic () {
    return Todos.find(
        { },
        { fields: Todos.fieldsExposed }
        );
});
```

I provide a rate limiter in "/imports/startup/server" folder as follows;

```
const todosPublication = {
    type: 'subscription',
    name: 'todos.public',
};
DDPRateLimiter.addRule(todosPublication, 1, 100);
```

And I test the limiter in a `React` component in the following code;

```
componentWillMount () {
        for (let i = 0; i < 25000; i++) {
            console.log('i');
            Meteor.subscribe('todos.public');
        }
    }
```

In the result I don't get any error, which means the limiter does not work.

Any idea?

Comment: That is not proof that the rate limiter is not working.

Comment: You can't honestly believe that `Meteor.subscribe` will subscribe 25000 times to the same publication.

Comment: Why? I inserted the same Meteor.subscribe() code in several other React components, too. But, I don't get any rate error, either. On the other hand, I see the rate limiter works properly for Meteor.Method() calls.

Comment: It does _not_ resubscribe (send any request to the server), because other 24999 subscribe calls do match the very first one. Have a look here: https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/master/packages/ddp-client/livedata_connection.js#L567-L573

Comment: On the other hand, `Meteor.subscribe('reminders.public', i)` should work. Try it.

Comment: @Styx I downloaded Meteor Chrome extension to see the details in the DDP traffic. Yes, I see "unsubscribed" messages to previous subscriptions with msg:"nosub" in the tool. I don't understand why I cannot see any error log in server or client. However, apparently, DDP rate-limiting is not a proper way to prevent DDoS attacks.

Comment: @Styx - even changing the subscription parameter doesn't cause a re-publish. The data sent via the publication will be updated but there won't be a new publication or subscription.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the OP is asserting a bug where none exists and isn't really asking a question.

Comment: Hehe, just noticed that your publication and limiter have `todos.public`, but you're subscribing to `reminders.public`. That's why `nosub` message :)

Comment: @GokhanKaradag - I feel that ddos checks should be done at a level higher than the app. If requests from a supposed ddos attack are reaching the app, then I feel that it is already too late. Have you looked at handling this at a firewall level as well?

Comment: @Styx, this part is correct in the code. It was a copy-paste error, sorry. I fixed it.